# PHP Populate Text box from Select - Array fields

Tags: php, javascript

I need to populate the relevant text box with the results of a Select drop down.

My Javascript so far is

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('error');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('errormsg_id');

mydropdown.onchange = function(){
     mytextbox.value = this.value;
}
</script>
```

My select box and text boxes are built as arrays from a query so there is nultiple of them.
I need to be able to populate the corresponding text box with the results from the Select next to it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
    <td width="1%">

    <select style="width:100%" name="errormsg_id[]"  id="errormsg_id[]">

    <?php do { ?> 

    <option value="<?php echo  $row_rserrormsg['errormsg_id']?>"
    <?php if ($row_rsdates['errormsg_id'] == $row_rserrormsg['errormsg_id'])                 {              echo("selected='selected'"); } ; ?> >
<?php echo $row_rserrormsg['error_message']?></option>

<?php } while ($row_rserrormsg = mysql_fetch_assoc($rserrormsg)); ?>

<?php  mysql_data_seek($rserrormsg, 0);
$row_rserrormsg = mysql_fetch_assoc($rserrormsg);?>
</select>
</td>  

<TD  align="center" class="adminuser">
<input style="width:96%;text-align:left;"  autocomplete="on"  title="Enter Error    Message" type="text" name="error[]" id="error[]" value="<?php echo $row_rsdates['error_message']; ?>" maxlength="100"/> 
</TD>
```

Comment: Please format your question, so that it is a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You will be using jQuery and Your HTML is like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><select class="my_select" name="errormsg_id1[]" id="errormsg_id1">...</select></td>
        <td><input name="errormsg_id1_txt" id="errormsg_id1_txt" title="..." />
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td><select class="my_select" name="errormsg_idX[]" id="errormsg_idX">...</select></td>
        <td><input name="errormsg_idX_txt" id="errormsg_idX_txt" title="..." />
    </tr>
</table>
```

this could be done using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_select').change(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'_txt').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Hope it is correct, have no time to test it...

Comment: The question is tagged a javascript. jQuery alternative is not required.

Comment: @Starx That's the reason for downvoting? Cos I recommend using of jQuery? If something is not required that doesn't mean somebody could recommend easier and better way of approaching the same solution as OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle/DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V4SVt/2/) on how to get it to work with sample selects:

I think this approach is a little better than @shadyyx since it removed the need for you to manually increment the input and select field names.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><select class="select" name="errormsg_id[]">
            <option val="test1">Test1</option>               
            <option val="test2">Test2</option>                
            <option val="test3">Test3</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><input class="error_text" name="errormsg_id_txt[]" title="..." />
</tr>
...
<tr>
    <td><select class="select" name="errormsg_id[]">               
            <option val="test1">Test1</option>               
            <option val="test2">Test2</option>                
            <option val="test3">Test3</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><input class="error_text" name="errormsg_id_txt[]" title="..." />
</tr>
</table>
```

And the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.select').change(function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().find('.error_text').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**NOTICE:** If you are using plain Javascript, see **[this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K4yTs/1/)**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><select class="select" name="errormsg_id[]" id="errormsg_id1" onChange="update('errormsg_id1')">
            <option val="test1">Test1</option>               
            <option val="test2">Test2</option>                
            <option val="test3">Test3</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><input class="error_text"name="errormsg_id_txt[]" id="errormsg_id_txt1" title="..." />
</tr>
...
<tr>
    <td><select class="select" name="errormsg_id[]" id="errormsg_id2" onChange="update('errormsg_id2')">               
            <option val="test1">Test1</option>               
            <option val="test2">Test2</option>                
            <option val="test3">Test3</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><input class="error_text" name="errormsg_id_txt[]" id="errormsg_id_txt2" title="..." />
</tr>
</table>
```

And Javascript:

```
function update(element){
    var e = document.getElementById(element);
    var id = element.substring(element.length-1);
    document.getElementById("errormsg_id_txt"+id).value = e.value;
}
```

Comment: Downvote could be removed. Both jQuery and Vanilla JS have been supplied.

Answer (score -1):

You need to think of way to uniquely identify your corresponding set of elements. The most convenient way I would suggest would be to use the primary key value of the data row.

And example would be like

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $id = $row['id']; //A primary key field


   echo '<input type="text" name="text'.$id.'" id="text'.$id.'" />';
   echo '<select name="select'.$id.'" id="select'.$id.'" />...</select>";
}
```

Next, call a function from the select menu, so that only the relevant text box is updated. Update the above select portion to read something similar to this.

```
echo '<select name="select'.$id.'" id="select'.$id.'" onchange="updateBox(\'text'.$id.'\', this.value)" />...</select>";
```

Now, create a very simple simple function to update the text box.

```
function updateBox(element, value) {
    el = document.getElementById(element);
    el.value = value;
}
```

Comment: I don't like using `onEvent` calls directly within elements in combination with pure JS. This is kinda old way solution... Consider You have 500 elements, each carrying `onchange="update('this', 'with this value')"`... While each element could have only a class (while mostly it has class defined) that You can hang event listener to...

Comment: @shadyyz, Old way or not. It is one of the way possible. That are better ways even without jquery. And No offence, But I dont think it is of any importance to me or the OP, whether you like it or not.